# Recording and publishing video streams on Samsung Smart TV

Tags: video, samsung-smart-tv, video-recording, smart-tv

I would like to capture video using the web camera on the Smart TV and publish it to a server such as FMS via rtmp. Does the SDK provide any way to access the camera and record videos. In addition, does the SDK provide a socket API to stream the recorder video to a server.

The SDK only provides the API to access the camera via start and stop. I haven't seen any Methods for a developer to access the streams captured by the camera.

http://www.samsungdforum.com/Guide/index.html?Foldername=api00004&Filename=camera_146.html